# Перебор объектов массива

Tags: javascript

Есть массив объектов. Из него нужно получить сумму полей price только из тех объектов у которых paid === true и pass совпадает с pass из первого объекта массива. Свой вариант написал. Возможно есть более рациональное решение? Спасибо!

```
    let array = [{
            "pass": 1,
            "order": [{
                "paid": true,
                "price": 450
            },{
                "paid": false,
                "price": 30
            }, {
                "paid": true,
                "price": 70
            }]
        }, {
            "pass": 2,
            "order": [{
                "paid": false,
                "price": 450
            }, {
                "paid": true,
                "price": 30
            }, {
                "paid": false,
                "price": 70
            }]
        },{
            "pass": 1,
            "order": [{
                "paid": true,
                "price": 450
            }, {
                "paid": false,
                "price": 30
            }, {
                "paid": true,
                "price": 70
            }]
        }
        ]
//----------- Мой вариант -----------

        let finAmount = 0;
        for(let item in array) {
            if(array[0].pass === array[item].pass) {
                let subAmount = 0;
                for(let subitem of array[item].order) {
                    if(subitem.paid === true) {
                        subAmount+=subitem.price;
                    }
                }
                finAmount+=subAmount
              }
             }
```

Comment: можно обойтись без переменной `subAmount`

Comment: Да, понял, спасибо. А относительно использованных циклов?

Comment: И можно переменную сделать `firstPass =  array[0].pass`, так будет чуточку быстрее. В хроме и мозиле разницы не заметите, а вот в Edge уже быстрее. https://jsperf.com/test-reference-variable/1